In Apache Superset issue with use of Jinja parameters
I am creating a dataset via sql lab, in this I wrote a query with a parameter. When I am running this query in SQL lab its working fine, but when I start creating chart by using this dataset, it starts showing below error

Error: (102, b"Incorrect syntax near ')'.DB-Lib error message 20018, severity 15:\nGeneral SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server\n")

My query in SQL lab:
SELECT * FROM dbo.AllPayments WHERE MSO IN {{ filter_values('MSO')|where_in }}

Parameter:
{
  "_filters": [
    {
      "col": "MSO",
      "op": "IN",
      "val": ["DEN", "Hathway"]
    }
  ]
}

what can be the issue?
I was expecting that when i place this chart on dashboard with criteria of field "MSO" then it would have passed the filter value selected by user to the parameter and the results would be filtered according to selected filter

check the scope of the filter, the scope should be enabled to the chart where you want to use this filter in jinja, then also check the syntax of jinja correctly written in the dataset of the chart, then it should work
